# How can I prevent R eating up all my RAM?

Tags: r, macos, memory

I use Mac OS X 10.6.8 (yeah, it's an old MBP but it works)...

Still, i think there's something not working properly. The machine gets dead slow but there should be around 1.12 GB left:

[image]

I have the feeling the memory is not allocated to the R program. Here no other software is running, and R is doing some stopword removal operation on a 600 MB corpus.

(I'm posting this here because i dont believe i could make it to apple.stackoverflow but feel free to migrate to a better forum).

How can I "free" the inactive RAM to either the system or the running application?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure of your actual application, but if you are storing large datasets in memory, then one way to reduce memory usage is to delete them after they are no longer needed using rm().  For example, if I load a large dataset "allData", and then filter it as "filteredData", then it would be best to remove allData by rm(allData) if it is not being used anymore.

Comment: I also find running `gc()` to be essential sometimes